# Adding actions to buttons in a subview

Tags: button, uiview, action

in my app i call a UIView and that UIView is like a settings screen in my app and i have buttons in the UIView and my question is how do i add actions to the buttons iv added to the UIViews subview? thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're writing code in a view controller for your settings UIView, the UIView is properly bound to the `view` property of your controller, and you have referenced one of the buttons with a variable `button`, here is what you would write:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(buttonPressed)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)buttonPressed
{
    // do things here in response to the button being pressed
}
```

Another way to write that method is passing in a pointer to the button which was actually pressed, like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(buttonPressed:) // note the extra colon here
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *buttonWhichWasPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
    // now you can do things like hide the button, change its text, etc.
}
```

Rather than calling `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`, though, in Interface Builder (*you should be doing this*) after defining the `buttonPressed` or `buttonPressed:` method above, in the `.xib` file with the button go to the second tab in the Inspector after clicking on the Button (it should say Button Connections), and click-drag the Touch Up Inside event to File's Owner, and select "buttonPressed" from the list.